# How to prove $\frac{a}{1998}+\frac{b}{1997}+\frac{c}{1996} \ge 0$ using Calculus only?

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

Let a,b,c are in $\mathbb{R} $ such that $ax^{2}+bx+c \ge0$ for every $x \ge 0$, show that $$\dfrac{a}{1998}+\dfrac{b}{1997}+\dfrac{c}{1996} \ge 0$$

Comment: the questionsaid calculus only @Justin

Comment: At least, $x=0$ implies that $c\geq 0$.

Comment: Justin's comment showed how to derive this inequality using only $x^2 \ge 0$. What's not to like? Are you looking for a more complex solution?

Comment: NO sir, i'm don't , but the question demands the solution using calculus only @MichałMiśkiewicz

Comment: can i multiply both sides with $x^{1995}$ then integrate from 0 to 1 , will that suffice ? @MichałMiśkiewicz

Comment: You mean that you're not allowed to perform any algebraic manipulations? It doesn't make sense to me. On a different note, try applying $ax^{2}+bx+c \ge 0$ with $x = \frac{1996}{1997}$. Edit: yes, this works.

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light Yes, I think that is the intended trick for this one. Something positive on an interval integrated will stay positive.

Comment: yeah the i was said to use calculus

Comment: But you should not stay satisfied with getting these tricks-by-design questions right. They work on problems specifically designed for it but seldom real world problems. Instead try learning to think in terms of systematic methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that we have $a\geq 0$, indeed, we have
$$0\leq \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty} a+\frac{b}{x}+\frac{c}{x^2}=a.$$
Now, let $\bar x= \frac{1996}{1997}$, then we have $\frac{1996}{1998}>\bar x^2$, hence it follows that
$$ \frac{1996}{1998}a+\frac{1996}{1997}b+c \geq \bar x^2a+b\bar x+c \geq 0.$$
The desired result is obtained by dividing the above equation by $1996$.

---

**EDIT:** To see that $\frac{1996}{1998}>\bar x^2$ by hand, you may proceed as follows:
For $s>0$, we have $$(s+1)^2 = s^2+2s+1>s^2+2s = s(s+2)\qquad \implies \qquad \frac{s+1}{s+2}>\frac{s}{s+1}.$$ With $s=1996$, it follows that
$$ \frac{1997}{1998}>\frac{1996}{1997} \qquad \implies \qquad \frac{1996}{1998}>\Big(\frac{1996}{1997}\Big)^2.$$